# react native application returns 404 error

Tags: laravel, react-native

I am creating app in react native with laravel backend.So as I want to get api from laravel server so i run laravel with that command

```
php artisan serve --host=some-domain.test --port=anyPort
```

I create api like that way

```
Route::get('users','PostController@get_users');
function get_users()
    {
        return Response()->json(User::get(),200);
    }
```

In react native I call that api in that way

```
constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state={
      data :[]
    }
  }
componentDidMount()
  {
    this.callApi();
  }
  async callApi()
  {
    
    let data=await fetch(' http://192.168.1.1:8081/api/users') //same as where laravel server is running
    let adata= await data.text();
    this.setState({data:adata})
    console.warn(data)  
  }
```

It returns me 404 error:`development server returned response error code:404`
but when i stop laravel server and refresh my app then start laravel server it return me that error

```
Possible unhandled promise rejection(id:0):
```

what should I do now ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling your Promise right hence you get the Error. The way that Fetch should be used is something like this:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

You can read more about it on the official Docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

If you want to set the State you would have to do it in the second .then() Call.

Also remeber to add a `.catch(err => console.log(err))` to filter your errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle cors request

You can install this package

```
https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

To generate config file run following command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"
```

and then update in config/cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

To allow CORS for all your routes, add the HandleCors middleware at the top of the `$middleware` property of `app/Http/Kernel.php` class:

```
protected $middleware = [
  \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    // ...
];
```